# Password Reset Auth using MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, axios, mern

I'm implementing an auth token within the nodemailer email that is sent whenever a user resets their password. I've got the generated url with the appended token setup and sending properly, I just can't seem to get my routing right to handle the authentication of said token.

My request is returning a 404 saying my GET is not found (GET http://localhost:3000/reset/XXXXXXXXXXXX 404 (Not Found) ). Could anyone help point me in the right direction here?

**Here's my api route for the server**

```
router.get('/reset', (req, res, next) => {
   User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.query.resetPasswordToken }).then(user => {
      if (user == null) {
         res.json('Password link is invalid or has expired');
      } else {
         res.status(200).send({
           username: user.email,
           message: 'Password link accepted',
         })
     }
   })
});
```

**And my code to handle the request**

```
componentDidMount() {

  console.log(this.props.match.params.token);

  axios.get('/reset' + this.props.match.params.token)
    .then(response => {
      // Conditional logic here based on response returned
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell express to expect the parameter in the url like this:

```
router.get('/reset/:token', (req, res, next) => {
   // token is inside req.params.token
   User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token }).then(user => {
      if (user == null) {
         res.json('Password link is invalid or has expired');
      } else {
         res.status(200).send({
           username: user.email,
           message: 'Password link accepted',
         })
     }
   })
});
```

Then make sure there is a slash in the url when you make the request:

```
  axios.get('/reset/' + this.props.match.params.token)
    .then(response => {
      // Conditional logic here based on response returned
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
```

Comment: It's still returning a console error of 404 with those edits made

Comment: This is the catch error here: Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)

Comment: @SethSpivey Well then your error is with some code you haven't shown. Are you sure the router is hooked into the main app properly? Post the code around the `app.use` statement that includes this router. On a site note though, the way you have it set up now, the request doesn't actually return a proper error. The `catch` on your axios call will never run unless you actually return an error status from the server. The `res.json()` part should be something like `res.status(400).json()`. You need to return a status code other than 2xx in order for the client to call the error callback.

Comment: I've got if figured out. In my request, I've reset the url to '/api/users/reset/'. i'm not quite sure why this would be necessary though. I've got my router setup with app.use("/api/users", users) and then I've got all of my routes stored in my users server file. With other update routes, I didn't have to define the /api/users to make it work..